# android - fetching limited json array for each cardview

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-volley, cardview

I am making use of cardview and every card has a pop menu which opens another activity. "data" array is displayed on the card and I want the respective array "document_list" to be displayed on opening of other activity. Below is the code but all of the items are getting displayed. So how do I limit or restrict ? data(id) == document_list(property_id).

**CARDVIEW FRAGMENT**

```
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,"URL",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        //converting the string to json array object
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                        if (object.getInt("status") == 200) {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("data");
                           // String userData = jsonArray.getString(0);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject pobj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                pobj.getString("id");
                                JSONObject pobj1 = new JSONObject(pobj.getString("owner_details"));
                                mylistList.add(new Mylist(
                                      //other elements
                                        pobj.getString("sas_application_no"),
                                        pobj1.getString("name"),
                                        pobj1.getString("mobile")
                                        ));
                            }
                        }
```

**CARDVIEW ADAPTER**

```
holder.buttonViewOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mCtx, holder.buttonViewOption);
            popup.inflate(R.menu.options_menu);
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        
                        case R.id.menu_document:
                            //handle menu2 click
                            id = mylist.getId();
                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            bundle.putString("id",id);
                            DocFragment newfragment1 = new DocFragment();
                            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction1 =((AppCompatActivity)mCtx).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            fragmentTransaction1.replace(R.id.container_view1, newfragment1);
                            fragmentTransaction1.addToBackStack(null);
                            fragmentTransaction1.commit();
                            NavigationActivity.container_view1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Doc_fragment is the new activity which opens the cardview with below code. So on click of R.id.menu_document: I need to pass the "id" which is to fetched from CARDVIEW FRAGMENT? How do I do it?

```
public class DocFragment extends Fragment {
//a list to store all the products
List<DocList> docList;
DocAdapter docAdapter;
//the recyclerview
RecyclerView recyclerView;
private String sid = "";

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_doc, container, false);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        sid = getArguments().getString("id");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), sid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    docList = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView1);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    //docList.add(new DocList("abc","123","asdf"));
    //creating recyclerview adapter
    docAdapter = new DocAdapter(getContext(), docList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(docAdapter);
    loadMenuData();

    return root;
}


public void loadMenuData() {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "url",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        //converting the string to json array object
                        //String selectedId = getIntent().getStringExtra("selectedId");
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                        if (object.getInt("status") == 200) {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("data");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject pobj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                if (!sid.equals(pobj.optString("id", "")))
                                    continue;
                                JSONArray jsonArray1 = pobj.getJSONArray("document_list");
                                for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray1.length(); j++) {
                                    JSONObject dobj = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(j);
                                    docList.add(new DocList(
                                            dobj.getString("document_name"),
                                            dobj.getString("description"),
                                            dobj.getString("doc_no")
                                    ));
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        //creating adapter object and setting it to recyclerview
                        docAdapter = new DocAdapter(getContext(), docList);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(docAdapter);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    //adding our stringrequest to queue
    Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext()).add(stringRequest);
}
```

}

```
{
"status": 200,
"data": [
    {
        "id": "5",
        "property_type": "AGRICULTURAL",
        "name": "A D  ",
        "site_no": "SY NO 21",
        "p_id_no": "21",
        "sas_application_no": "13",
        "latitude": "12",
        "longitude": "33",
        "status": "OWNED",
        "purchase_year": "2007",
        "owner_details": {
            "name": "A D",
            "mobile": "776006"
        },
        "size": "41724",
        "unit": "SQF",
        "document_list": [
            {
                "property_id": "5",
                "document_type_id": "4",
                "file_path": "https://demoapi.dyuppar.in/uploads",
                "document_name": "Encumbrance Certificate",
                "description": null,
                "doc_no": null
            },
            {
                "property_id": "5",
                "document_type_id": "3",
                "file_path": "https://demoapi.dyuppar.in/uploads",
                "document_name": "Mother Deed",
                "description": null,
                "doc_no": null
            },
            {
                "property_id": "5",
                "document_type_id": "84",
                "file_path": "https://demoapi.dyuppar.in/uploads",
                "document_name": "MUTATION COPY ",
                "description": null,
                "doc_no": null
            },
            {
                "property_id": "5",
                "document_type_id": "87",
                "file_path": "https://demoapi.dyuppar.in/uploads",
                "document_name": "OLD E C",
                "description": null,
                "doc_no": null
            },
            {
                "property_id": "5",
                "document_type_id": "83",
                "file_path": "https://demoapi.dyuppar.in/uploads",
                "document_name": "OTHER DOCUMENTS ",
                "description": null,
                "doc_no": null
            },
                    ]
    },
    {
        "id": "9",
        "property_type": "AGRICULTURAL",
        "name": "A D ",
        "site_no": "SY NO 19/1 ",
        "p_id_no": "19/1",
        "sas_application_no": "12",
        "latitude": "12",
        "longitude": "45",
        "status": "OWNED",
        "purchase_year": "2007",
        "owner_details": {
            "name": "A D ",
            "mobile": "7760906"
        },
        "size": "2",
        "unit": "ACR",
        "document_list": [
            {
                "property_id": "9",
                "document_type_id": "4",
                "file_path": "https://demoapi.dyuppar.in/uploads",
                "document_name": "Encumbrance Certificate",
                "description": null,
                "doc_no": null
            },
            {
                "property_id": "9",
                "document_type_id": "43",
                "file_path": "https://demoapi.dyuppar.in/uploads",
                "document_name": "GPA",
                "description": null,
                "doc_no": null
            },
            
        ]
    },
```

Comment: What are you passing through an intent to call that activity? And how are you receiving in the other activity? Can you please some code and example for that?

Comment: @ Mayur Gajra - Im not passing anything through intent. In both the activities I have passed the same URL.(cardview is working fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

In your CardViewFragment set the arguments when the card is selected like following:

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.menu_document:
                //handle menu2 click
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("selectedId",selectedId);//get this id from your object/model .e.g list.get(postion).getId() , do it as per your strcuture setup. 
                DocFragment newfragment1 = new DocFragment();
                newfragment1.setArguments(bundle);
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction1 =((AppCompatActivity)mCtx).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction1.replace(R.id.container_view1, newfragment1);
                fragmentTransaction1.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction1.commit();
                NavigationActivity.container_view1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
        }
```

In your `DocFragment` create a global variable and match it with the data coming from your source.

```
private String selectedId = "";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            selectedId = getArguments().getString("selectedId");
        }
    }
```

Then match that id while fetching in `DocFragment`

```
        try {
            //converting the string to json array object
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
            if (object.getInt("status") == 200) {
                JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject pobj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // compare id passed from main activity, which was selected by user
                    if (!selectedId.equals(pobj.optString("id", "")))
                        continue;
                    JSONArray jsonArray1 = pobj.getJSONArray("document_list");
                    for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray1.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject dobj = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(j);
                        docList.add(new DocList(
                                dobj.getString("document_name"),
                                dobj.getString("description"),
                                dobj.getString("doc_no")
                        ));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

Comment: Ok but I have a cardview fragment and cardview adapter(in this adapter I have a popup menu) so through the popup menu Im calling the new fragment(so id shd be passed here but intent isnt working)

Comment: @AparnaMutnalkar Can you please update your code in the question of how you're calling the fragment? and what you're receiving in other fragment?

Comment: @AparnaMutnalkar See updated answer and let me know if this helps.

Comment: I updated thank u but if (getArguments() != null) {
            selectedId = getArguments().getString("selectedId");
        } is blank. I tried displaying in toast

Comment: Did you check what you're passing in `bundle.putString("selectedId",selectedId);`  is not empty? If not please update your latest code with what you've tried.

Comment: @AparnaMutnalkar see my above comment

Comment: I have updated the code. Here bundle.putString("selectedId",selectedId) its fetching the id I checked

Comment: @ Mayur Gajra - Your code is perfect!! Mistake on my part. I missed the newfragment1.setArguments(bundle); statement. Thank u..